# Unity3d Line drawing with colourable material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project that a client had developed years ago by another developer. They are now looking to bring the project up to date and make new changed etc. Of the projects features is a colouring screen where you can select a colour and a 'pen size' and draw on the screen.

The code to do this no longer functions correctly under the latest Unity3D and instead of setting the colour correctly just draws pink lines. Its my understanding that this is because the material for the line isn't being set.

The script thats being used is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ContinuousLine;


/// <summary>
/// This class implements on-screen drawing as a post-render process.
/// </summary>



public class OnScreenDrawing : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The color of the line.
    /// </summary>
    public Color lineColor = Color.black;

    public AudioClip Pressbutton;

    public bool clearing = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The size of the line.
    /// </summary>
    [Range (-1, 20)] public int lineSize = 5;

    /// <summary>
    /// The line material (shader) used for drawing the lines.
    /// </summary>
    private Material lineMaterial;

    /// <summary>
    /// The previous mouse position.
    /// </summary>
    private Vector2 prevPos = Vector2.zero;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current mouse position.
    /// </summary>
    private Vector2 currPos = Vector2.zero;

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of continuous lines.
    /// </summary>
    private List<Line> lines;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current line being drawn.
    /// </summary>
    private Line currLine;

    public void coln () {
        lineColor = new Color(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void colq () {
        lineColor = new Color(11.0f, 148.0f, 68.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void colw () {
        lineColor = new Color(255.0f, 242.0f, 0.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void cole () {
        lineColor = new Color(101.0f, 153.0f, 255.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void cola () {
        lineColor = new Color(255.0f, 153.0f, 0.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void cols () {
        lineColor = new Color(237.0f, 28.0f, 36.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void cold () {
        lineColor = new Color(53.0f, 53.0f, 53.0f) / 255.0f;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void allgone () {
        clearing = true;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void smalls () {
        lineSize = 5;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void meds () {
        lineSize = 19;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void bigs () {
        lineSize = 35;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
    }

    public void returns () {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot (Pressbutton);
        Application.LoadLevel ("PaintingMenu");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        lines = new List<Line>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Left mouse button pressed.
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            prevPos     = Input.mousePosition;
            currLine    = new Line(lineColor, lineSize, prevPos);

            lines.Add(currLine);
        }

        // Left mouse button held down.
        else if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
            currPos = Input.mousePosition;
            if (currPos != prevPos) {
                currLine.AddPoint(currPos);
                prevPos = currPos;
            }
        }

        // Left mouse button released.
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1")) {

        }

        // Spacebar pressed. Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
        else if (clearing == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
                lines[i].ClearPoints();
            lines.Clear();
            clearing = false;
        }

        // Change sizes.
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("1")) {
            lineSize = 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("2")) {
            lineSize = 5;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("3")) {
            lineSize = 15;
        }

        // Change colors
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)) {
            lineColor = new Color(9.0f, 112.0f, 84.0f) / 255.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
            lineColor = new Color(255.0f, 222.0f, 0.0f) / 255.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            lineColor = new Color(101.0f, 153.0f, 255.0f) / 255.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
            lineColor = new Color(255.0f, 153.0f, 0.0f) / 255.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
            lineColor = new Color(210.0f, 67.0f, 60.0f) / 255.0f;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
            lineColor = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) / 255.0f;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        //GUI.Label(new Rect(5.0f, 0.0f, 250.0f, 25.0f), "Press 'Space' to clear");
        //GUI.Label(new Rect(5.0f, 15.0f, 250.0f, 25.0f), "Press '1', '2' or '3' to change sizes...");
        //GUI.Label(new Rect(5.0f, 30.0f, 300.0f, 25.0f), "Press 'q', 'w', 'e', 'a', 's' or 'd' to change colors...");
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {
        // Assign and set the current line material.
        Line.AssignLineMaterial(ref lineMaterial);
        lineMaterial.SetPass(0);

        // Setup the matrix stacks.
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadPixelMatrix();

        // Setup the viewport.
        GL.Viewport(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height));

        // Draw the lines.
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            lines[i].Draw();

        // Restore the matrix stacks.
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Looking at this I have found that `lineMaterial` is never set to anything so assume thats the issue however when I set up a basic Material and assign it to lineMaterial all I then get is black lines. How can I set up a material correctly so that the lines are drawn with the correct colour?

Thank you

Comment: `Line.AssignLineMaterial` is not part of Unity. Why didn't you post that?

Comment: Its from an assembled packaged "ContinuousLineDLL"

Comment: Which may well be the issue... because its wrapped in a dll Its possible I won't be able to fix this. But any suggestions on an alternative are also welcome

Comment: It's still not part of Unity. That's from a plugin from another person. You may want to contact the Author and and ask him/her why it's not working. Meanwhile, there is another way to draw a line in Unity if you care.....

Comment: Having found the author of the plugin it looks like it hasn't been touched since 2013 so its safe to say its no longer maintained. I would rather move the code base for this feature to something that is Unity native or using a maintained plugin yes.

Comment: You just want to draw colored line with the `lines` array?

Comment: @Programmer Sorry about the delay, yes I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin is old and has not been updated for a long time. You don't even need a plugin to draw a line. Unity's [*`GL`*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) API can be used to draw lines without any plugin. Use [`GL.Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.Color.html) to specify the line's color.

The [*`GL`*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) API is a low level way to draw a line. Although, I suggest you use Unity's [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) to do this as it simplifies drawing lines. This means that you have to re-write the whole code that draw the lines in the app.

Below is a simple function that draws a line based on the provided `Vector3` array you passed to it via [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html). It draws and closes the line(connects first index to last index). No plugin required.

```
//Draws lines through the provided vertices
void drawLine(Vector3[] verticesToDraw)
{
    Color beginColor = Color.yellow;
    Color endColor = Color.red;
    float lineWidth = 0.3f;

    //Create a Line Renderer Obj then make it this GameObject a parent of it
    GameObject childLineRendererObj = new GameObject("LineObj");
    childLineRendererObj.transform.SetParent(transform);

    //Create new Line Renderer if it does not exist
    LineRenderer lineRenderer = childLineRendererObj.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    if (lineRenderer == null)
    {
        lineRenderer = childLineRendererObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    //Assign Material to the new Line Renderer
    //Hidden/Internal-Colored
    //Particles/Additive
    lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored"));


    //Set color
    lineRenderer.startColor = beginColor;
    lineRenderer.endColor = endColor;

    //Set width
    lineRenderer.startWidth = lineWidth;
    lineRenderer.endWidth = lineWidth;

    //Convert local to world points
    for (int i = 0; i < verticesToDraw.Length; i++)
    {
        verticesToDraw[i] = gameObject.transform.TransformPoint(verticesToDraw[i]);
    }

    //5. Set the SetVertexCount of the LineRenderer to the Length of the points
    lineRenderer.positionCount = verticesToDraw.Length + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < verticesToDraw.Length; i++)
    {
        //Draw the  line
        Vector3 finalLine = verticesToDraw[i];
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, finalLine);

        //Check if this is the last loop. Now Close the Line drawn
        if (i == (verticesToDraw.Length - 1))
        {
            finalLine = verticesToDraw[0];
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(verticesToDraw.Length, finalLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code although im not sure how to implement this in a way that replaces the current script